# Remove a td based on its content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, contains

I have a `td` with an image inside it I want to remove the whole `td` based on the directory of the image inside it.
The source code:

```
<td width="1" valign="top"><img src="/PBox_Border_Right_Top.gif" alt=""></td>
```

So I was looking for something like

```
td:contains img[src=image/source.gif].remove()
```

Comment: And the name of the directory would be..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ojivuv/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
$('td img[src^="directory"]').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('td:has(img[src^="/path/to/remove"])').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .has() or :has

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2xANA/1/

has() reference: http://api.jquery.com/has/

```
$("td:has(img[src='image/source.gif'])").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').children('img[src^="image/"]').remove();
```

This will select all image elements that are direct children of td elements and have a `src` attribute that starts with `image/` (the image will be removed with the `.remove()` function call). You can change `image/` to whatever you want to select the image directory you want.

Comment: This will remove the image, not the cell.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Yeah I state that in the answer, `.parent().remove();` to remove the table cell.